# Two map reduce jobs and joining reduced values of each job into one list of two values

Tags: java, hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce, reduce

I am writing a MapReduce program requiring me to find the number of inbound and outbound links of a node (000-999), essentially a web-graph processor. I need to return a particular node as the key and the out-degree and in-degree of each document as the value. For example, the

sample text file:

```
000 002
001 002
002 000
001 000
```

should return:

```
000 1 2
001 2 0
002 1 2
```

By my logic, it seems like I need to create two map reduce jobs, the first passing in a LongWritable key with the value as the pair of nodes (eg. 000 002), counting the number of outbound links from each node and returning something like (000 1) at the end of the reducer phase. Then I would find the in-degree of the document by flipping the pairs of nodes (eg. 000 002 becomes 002 000) and finding the count of those outbound links(in the above example, this would return (000 2)). Then I need to combine those values to make a final output of (000 1 2). Is the best approach to create two map jobs, and somehow join those two values into a list of two values? If i'm using java (not Hive) to code this, is there a way to join those values? Is there a much easier and more efficient way to solve this?

Edit: For this program, the mapper functionality is the same, because I am merely switching the two values (000 002 to 002 000) in order to compute inbound paths and outbound paths in the exact same manner. The reducer function is the exact same as well, but it needs to be run on two separate jobs, so I do not receive my final value as the sum of the in-degree and out-degree. I need to return the in-degree, and then return the out-degree and append them in a list of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Suggestion is to make a more complex intermediate format using a complex String. All you might need is to form a CSV format for your reducer.

For every line that goes to your reducer, there will be 2 different Nodes: 000 and 002 in the first line of your input.
make a '#' separated string such as:

```
context.write(new Text("000"),new Text("LeftToRight#1"));
context.write(new Text("002"),new Text("RightToLeft#1"));
```

Later in the reducer you can count all the LeftToRights and RightToLeft seperately and make an output for them.

To get the output in a single file: set number of reducers to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would like to do other stuff then calculating the degree of a given vertex, i recommend using  [jgrapht](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht), a Java class library which provides objects and algorithms for graph theory.

See [inDegreeOf](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/DirectedGraph.html#inDegreeOf%28V%29) as a solution for you problem.